# how to clear search result while click in search button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a song and a lyric searching page. The first time search is working well but while I click in the search button the previous result remains and also search results also shown on the page.

Now I want to disappear the result while searching for another song or lyric.
And also I want to make the search the result same style but I don't get results as I wanted.

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const result = document.getElementById('result');
// api url
const api= 'https://api.lyrics.ovh';

// song lyrics

function getLyrics (artist, title) {
    let url = `${api}/v1/${artist}/${title}`
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(singerLyrics => {
        const lyrics = singerLyrics.lyrics;
        const getLyric = document.getElementById('getLyric');
        getLyric.innerHTML = `<h2 class="text-success mb-4">${artist} - ${title}</h2>
        <pre class="lyric text-white">${lyrics}</pre>`;
    });
    result.innerHTML= '';
}

// search by song or artist

function searchSongs(term){
    fetch(`${api}/suggest/${term}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then (showData);
};

// search result

function showData (data) {
    result.innerHTML = `<div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
    <div class="col-md-9"> ${data.data.map(song => `<h3 class="lyrics-name">${song.title}</h3>
        <p class="author lead">${song.type} by <span>${song.artist.name}</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
        <button onclick="getLyrics('${song.artist.name}','${song.title}')" class="btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
    </div>
</div>`)};
    `;

   
};

//event listeners

search.addEventListener('click', function searchResult (){
    const inputText =  text.value.trim();
    
    if (!inputText){
        alert('this is not a song or artist')
    }else {
        searchSongs(inputText);
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #13141b;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(images/bg-image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top;
}

.form-control{
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 22px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.btn{
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    padding: 9px 20px;
}

.btn-privious{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
}
.search-box{
    position: relative;
}
.search-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.single-result{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hard Rock Solution - Song Lyric App</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-dark my-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hard Rock Solution">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <img src="images/toggler-icon.svg" alt="">
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownId">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="content-area">
            <div class="search-bar col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <h1 class="text-center">Lyrics Search</h1>
                <div class="search-box my-5">
                    <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your artist song name">
                    <button id="search" class="btn btn-success search-btn">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- === Simple results === -->
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div id="result" class="">
            </div>
            <!-- Single Lyrics -->
            <div  id="getLyric" id="artistTitle" class="single-lyrics text-center">
              </div>
            </div>
       </main>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Script Here -->
    <script src ="javascrpt.js"> </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Add `result.innerHTML = '';` In your search `click` listener **else** case before `searchSongs(inputText);` call. Try posting more details in question rather that links. Which helps other here to answer your question better and faster. @john

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I will try my best.

Comment: Hello, I change the question and added more details.

Answer (score 0):

try to use autocomplete="off" like

```
    <input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time, search is clicked, the lyrics container should be emtpied:

```
document.querySelector("#getLyric").childNodes.forEach(el => el.remove())
```

to fix the issue, add this to your script:

```
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector("#getLyric").innerHTML = '';
})
```